# How to recursively extract archives in separate folders, passwords for them in the format "pass.txt" contained with the archive in its folder

Tags: password, directory, archive, extract

folder1/file.zip file1.zip-pass.txt

folder2/file2.7z file2.7z-pass.txt

folder3/file.001 file.002 file.00?-pass.txt

if I structure the archives and their passwords like this, can I recursively extract each respective archive in its folder?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 20.04